# Changing html tags with line break Jquery / Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a page where the User enters a structure tags in and he converts tables to structure "ul" "li".

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>Beta style</title>
        <script type='text/javascript' src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.js'></script>
        <script>
                function gerador() {
                     var code = $('textarea[name=message]').val();
                     /* prevent the creation of multiple output-blocks if someone clicks on the submit-button more than once */
                     if ($('#output').length < 1) {
                         $("body").append('<h2>Output</h2><textarea id="output" rows="10" cols="100"></textarea>');
                     }
                     /* replace all the things you want */
                     code = code.replace(/\<table>/g, "<ul>");
                     code = code.replace(/\<\/table>/g, "</ul>");
                     code = code.replace(/\<td>/g, "<li>");
                     code = code.replace(/\<\/td>/g, "</li>");
                     code = code.replace(/\<tr>/g, "");
                     code = code.replace(/\<\/tr>/g, "");
                     code = code.replace(/\TEXT/g, "<label>TEXT</label>");
                     /* output the new code */
                     $('#output').val(code);
               }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h2>Input</h2>
        <textarea name="message" id="input" rows="10" cols="100"></textarea>
        <input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="gerador();" />
    </body>
</html>
```

What I'm trying is to replace all that you have is so

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <label>TEXT:<label> 
    </li>
    <li>
        <input type="text" value="" />
    </li>
</ul>
```

for

```
<ul>
     <li>
         <label>TEXT:<label> 
         <input type="text" value="" />
     </li>
</ul>
```

ie replace the tag by and `../>` by `.` The problem that exists is that as line breaks indentation, the jquery code does not work.

```
code = code.replace("</label> \r\n </li>", "</label>");
code = code.replace("<li> \r\n <input>", "<input>");
```

Thanks!!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [**RegEx match open tags...**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Comment: $("ul").find("li:first").remove(); $("ul").find("li:last").append("<label>TEXT:<label>");

Comment: Matching html with regular expression is a bad idea...Would be better to make it an html nodeset and loop through and generate the content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Matching HTML with regular expressions is not that wise. It is better to build it off the DOM instead. Using map() you can build the string pretty easy.

```
var htmlStr = '<table><tr><td><label>XXX</label></td><td><input type="text"/></td></tr><tr><td><label>YYY</label></td><td><input type="text"/></td></tr></table>';

var lis = $(htmlStr).find("tr").map(function () {            //loop through the tabel rows
    var cellContents = $(this).find("td").map(function () {  //find the cells and loop through
        return $(this).html();                               //get the elements inside of the cells
    }).get().join("");                                       //map results in an array, get it and make it a string
    return "<li>" + cellContents + "</li>";                  //return the li with the cell contents
}).get().join("");                                           //take the li array and make it a sting
var yourUL = "<ul>" + lis + "</ul>";                         //build your ul with the lis
```

If you want indenting, you just have to add it when you build the strings.

```
var lis = $(htmlStr).find("tr").map(function () {
    var cellContents = $(this).find("td").map(function () {
        return "\t\t" + $(this).html();
    }).get().join("\n");
    return "\t<li>\n" + cellContents + "\n\t</li>";
}).get().join("\n");
var yourUL = "<ul>\n" + lis + "\n</ul>";
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/GD8Yu/

Comment: WORKING! Incredible! :)